# Examples of a $5000 website. (For a guide on pricing)

Tags: website-design, designers, freelance

I realize this may sound like a strange question (and hopefully relevant for this site). I am starting up freelancing and am unsure about what I should charge for various jobs.

Would other freelancers be able to show me examples of a website they would charge $5000 to make? If not $5000 then specify how much for the individual website.

Answer (score 4):

Cost is a factor of many things. Mainly how long you expect to take to complete the work and what your hourly rate is expected to be. Since you are not specifying where you are its impossible to say. Pricing varies so heavily on your location because the cost of living is so wildly different i  different places, even within a country.

Even the clients themselves affect the price quite heavily. A bigger organisation would more likely pay more for a equivalent webpage. Mostly because they can affort do pay, though also because they usualy want guarantees, may work slower (more meetings), may want special legal terms etc. So cost is affected quite much also by the way the client expects to be treated, if they expect to micromanage and have lots of "free" revisions then the cost is higher.

All in all you can not often see the amount of money used from the webpage alone. Some things sich as arranging a photoshoot increase price. While comparable stock photos do not. I have seen lots of 10,000€ sites that do not appreciatedly differ from a 1000€ site.

Comment: Very useful information thanks Joojaa. For the record I'm from New Zealand, just out of university, so I'm new to the business side of it all. It would still be interesting to see peoples examples even considering what you said. Too bad my reputation is too low to upvote your answer :/.

Comment: @MaxPower - What joojaa is saying is that there is nothing you could point to either in what shows up in your browser window or in the source HTML, CSS, JS, etc. files that will tell you whether it cost $500 or $500K. If you've seen a really pretty website, you've seen a $5K example. If you've seen a really ugly website, you've seen a $5K example. Single static page of barely-formatted text? Yep. Terabytes of backing data making billions of pages? That too. There's no way to tell what the money paid for from the outside.

Comment: @StanRogers I see where he's coming from, thanks for clarifying it even more.